# Как заменить анимацию при вставке элементов в UICollectionView на scroll?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Предполагаю, что сначала надо отключить анимацию а потом вызвать скролл. Как отключить анимацию ?

вставка элемента:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            for (APIServiceItem *item in items) {
                [self.uids insertObject:item.uid atIndex:0];
                [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];

            }
        }completion:nil];
```

вызов скрола:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы отключить анимацию (везде): `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];`

Comment: точно, можно отключить анимацию, проскролить и включить анимацию